# Validating a date format in c++

Tags: c++, date, if-statement, ostringstream

I'm trying to validate a date format on on a line such as this one (01 10 2017) by creating a stream.

```
        if(i%5==4){ //DATE
            std::string date;
            int day;
            int month;
            int year;
            std::ostringstream oss(date);
            oss >> day;
            oss >> month;
            oss >> year;
            if (day >=0 && day <= 31){
                return true;}
            if (month >=01 && month <= 12){
                return true;}
            if (year >=1900){
                return true;}
        }
```

However, the code doesn't compile. What could I do to improve the validation?

Thank you

Comment: I'm afraid you reversed the stream insert operator `<<`.

Comment: AFAIK `std::ostream` does not have `operator>>()`.

Comment: May be worth looking at [std::get_time](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time).

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps.

```
    if(i%5==4){ //DATE
        std::string date;
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;
        std::ostringstream oss(date);
        oss << day;
        oss << month;
        oss << year;
        const int lookup_table[12] = {31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
        if (!(month >= 1 && month <= 12)){
            return false;}
        if (!(day >= 1 && day <= lookup_table[month-1])){
            return false;}
        if (!(year >= 1900)){
            return false;}
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> What could I do to improve the validation?

Use a well-tested date/time library such as [Howard Hinnant's free, open source, header-only date/time library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html).

```
bool
is_DMY(const std::string& date)
{
    std::istringstream in{date};
    date::year_month_day ymd;
    in >> date::parse("%d %m %Y", ymd);
    return !in.fail();
}
```

Example use:

```
int
main()
{
    std::cout << is_DMY("30 09 2017") << '\n';
    std::cout << is_DMY("31 09 2017") << '\n';
}
```

which outputs:

```
1
0
```

This demonstrates that the first test in the OP:

```
       if (day >=0 && day <= 31){
            return true;}
```

will prematurely return `true` for "31 09 2017".  There are only 30 days in Sep.